# Best way for retrieve custom data attribute from event in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I was wondering what is the best way for retrieve the value of a custom data HTML attribute with Meteor from event object?

eg:

**articles.html**

```
   <template name="createArticle">
    <form class="new-article">
        <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="New title"/>
        <input type="text" name="content" placeholder="New content" />
        <!-- list categ -->
      <label>Category
        <select id="categ-list" name="categ">
          {{#each categories}}
            <option value="{{name}}" data-id={{_id}}>{{name}}</option>
          {{/each}}
        </select>
      </label>
        <input type ="submit" value= "Create" class="button">
    </form>
</template>
```

**articles.js**

```
   Template.createArticle.events({
  "submit .new-article": function(event){
    var title = event.target.title.value;
    var content = event.target.content.value;
    var categName = event.target.categ.value;
    var categId = event.target.categ.data('id'); // HERE
    console.log("test " + categId);
    Meteor.call("addArticle", title, content, categId, categName);
    event.target.title.value = "";
    event.target.content.value = "";
    return false;
    },
    "click #categ-list": function(event){
console.log('click');
    }
  });
```

How can I get the `data-id` attribute value in the event handler?

EDIT: Add more code

EDIT2:

```
console.log(event.target.categ)
```

output:

```
<select id="categ-list" name="categ"> 
<option value="test" data-id="p5zKaEbEiRkQjCkGg">test</option> 
<option value="test1" data-id="okPY6oyeXiFR7M3jd">test1</option> 
</select>
```

Comment: please show your entire event handler. Which element is the event coming from?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

DOM elements ([`HTMLElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement) objects) don't have `.data()` method. [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) method belongs to jQuery objects. If you are using jQuery you should wrap the element with jQuery constructor then use the `.data` method:

```
$(event.target.categ).data('id');
```

Another option is using [`.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) property <sup>1</sup>:

```
event.target.categ.dataset.id;
```

Or [`.getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) method:

```
event.target.categ.getAttribute('data-id');
```

**update**:

You should also select the selected option before using `dataset` property.

```
var sel = event.target.categ;
var categId = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-id');
```

---

<sup>1.  IE10 and below partially support the property. [Android 2.3 cannot read `data-*` properties from `select` elements.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=dataset)</sup>

Comment: <select id="categ-list" name="categ">
          
            <option value="test" data-id="p5zKaEbEiRkQjCkGg"></option>
          
            <option value="test1" data-id="okPY6oyeXiFR7M3jd"></option>
     </select>

Comment: @JulienLeray I found the problem. The `select`  element itself doesn't have `data-id` property, you should select the selected `option` before using the property.

Comment: Thanks it's working. It's really JS is verbose for this kind of tasks btw!

Comment: You are welcome! Yes, that's why libraries like jQuery are so popular. It's not fault of JavaScript. It's DOM that has terrible APIs.

Comment: For those extrapolating this to their own code, I had to take out the `categ` to get it to work. `e.target.dataset.id`

Answer (score 4):

**First of all:**
If you want to get the selected element in meteor, you do not need jQuery. Just take the change event and get the data with JavaScript:

```
Template.show.events({
    'change #options': function (event) {
        var currentTarget = event.currentTarget;
        console.log('Selected Value: ' + currentTarget.options[currentTarget.selectedIndex].value);
        console.log('Selected data: ' + currentTarget.options[currentTarget.selectedIndex].dataset.id);
    }
});
```

**Secondly:**
To get the data of the element you should always use `event.currentTarget.dataset`.

By using `event.target.dataset` you will get the wrong dataset in some cases.

E.g.:

```
<template name="show">
  <div class="target" data-id="1">
    <h1>Category with id 1</h1>
    <div class="anotherTarget" data-id="15">
      Object with id 15
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.show.events({
    'click .target': function (event) {
      var currentTarget = event.currentTarget.dataset;
      var target = event.target.dataset;
      console.log(`CurrentTarget: $(currentTarget.id)`);
      console.log(`Target: $(target.id)`);
    }
  });
}
```

event.target gives you the element, you clicked on. In some cases this can be a child of the element you set the handler on.

event.currentTarget returns always the element you set the handler on.

Here is the example:
http://currenttarget.meteor.com/

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are trying to get the data-id of the currently selected option, try this if you are using jquery:

```
var categId = $(event.target.categ).find(':selected').data("id");
```

Comment: Note that the plain JavaScript version will fail.

Comment: Thanks for you're help it's working too, I upvote you but I have validated @Vohuman, sorry for that... (I figured out what you mean by the validated answer, but there is a little fail, data() should be replace by getAttribute() )